# Pgpool2: unable to read message kind

Tags: postgresql, pgpool

I managed to configure Pgpool using 3 virtual machines on my pc, but when I repeated the same procedure on a VPS it gives the following error

> child pid 5286: ERROR: unable to read message kind
> child pid 5286: DETAIL: kind does not match between main(53) slot[1] (4e)

I'm using 3 VPS a master on one machine, a slave on a second machine and pgpooll on a third machine

Replication is working normally, I just can't get pgpool to work

From pgpool VPS I can access both databases using psql normally
my pgpoll settings

```
 ----------------------------
# pgPool-II configuration file
# ----------------------------
#
# This file consists of lines of the form:
#
#   name = value
#
# Whitespace may be used.  Comments are introduced with "#" anywhere on a line.
# The complete list of parameter names and allowed values can be found in the
# pgPool-II documentation.
#
# This file is read on server startup and when the server receives a SIGHUP
# signal.  If you edit the file on a running system, you have to SIGHUP the
# server for the changes to take effect, or use "pgpool reload".  Some
# parameters, which are marked below, require a server shutdown and restart to
# take effect.
#

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# BACKEND CLUSTERING MODE
# Choose one of: 'streaming_replication', 'native_replication',
#   'logical_replication', 'slony', 'raw' or 'snapshot_isolation'
# (change requires restart)
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

backend_clustering_mode = 'streaming_replication'

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# CONNECTIONS
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# - pgpool Connection Settings -

listen_addresses = '*'
                                   # Host name or IP address to listen on:
                                   # '*' for all, '' for no TCP/IP connections
                                   # (change requires restart)
port = 9999
                                   # Port number
                                   # (change requires restart)
#socket_dir = '/var/run/postgresql'
                                   # Unix domain socket path
                                   # The Debian package defaults to
                                   # /var/run/postgresql
                                   # (change requires restart)
#reserved_connections = 0
                                   # Number of reserved connections.
                                   # Pgpool-II does not accept connections if over
                                   # num_init_chidlren - reserved_connections.


# - pgpool Communication Manager Connection Settings -

#pcp_listen_addresses = 'localhost'
                                   # Host name or IP address for pcp process to listen on:
                                   # '*' for all, '' for no TCP/IP connections
                                   # (change requires restart)
#pcp_port = 9898
                                   # Port number for pcp
                                   # (change requires restart)
#pcp_socket_dir = '/var/run/postgresql'
                                   # Unix domain socket path for pcp
                                   # The Debian package defaults to
                                   # /var/run/postgresql
                                   # (change requires restart)
#listen_backlog_multiplier = 2
                                   # Set the backlog parameter of listen(2) to
                                   # num_init_children * listen_backlog_multiplier.
                                   # (change requires restart)
#serialize_accept = off
                                   # whether to serialize accept() call to avoid thundering herd problem
                                   # (change requires restart)

# - Backend Connection Settings -

backend_hostname0 = '{my-ip-1}'
                                   # Host name or IP address to connect to for backend 0
backend_port0 = 5432
                                   # Port number for backend 0
backend_weight0 = 0
                                   # Weight for backend 0 (only in load balancing mode)
#backend_data_directory0 = '/data'
                                   # Data directory for backend 0
backend_flag0 = 'DISALLOW_TO_FAILOVER'
                                   # Controls various backend behavior
                                   # ALLOW_TO_FAILOVER, DISALLOW_TO_FAILOVER
                                   # or ALWAYS_PRIMARY
#backend_application_name0 = 'server0'
                                   # walsender's application_name, used for "show pool_nodes" command
backend_hostname1 = '{my-ip-2}'
backend_port1 = 5432
backend_weight1 = 1
#backend_data_directory1 = '/etc/postgresql/15/main'
backend_flag1 = 'DISALLOW_TO_FAILOVER'
#backend_application_name1 = 'server2'

# - Authentication -

#enable_pool_hba = off
                                   # Use pool_hba.conf for client authentication
#pool_passwd = 'pool_passwd'
                                   # File name of pool_passwd for md5 authentication.
                                   # "" disables pool_passwd.
                                   # (change requires restart)
#authentication_timeout = 1min
                                   # Delay in seconds to complete client authentication
                                   # 0 means no timeout.

#allow_clear_text_frontend_auth = off
                                   # Allow Pgpool-II to use clear text password authentication
                                   # with clients, when pool_passwd does not
                                   # contain the user password

# - SSL Connections -

#ssl = off
                                   # Enable SSL support
                                   # (change requires restart)
#ssl_key = 'server.key'
                                   # SSL private key file
                                   # (change requires restart)
#ssl_cert = 'server.crt'
                                   # SSL public certificate file
                                   # (change requires restart)
#ssl_ca_cert = ''
                                   # Single PEM format file containing
                                   # CA root certificate(s)
                                   # (change requires restart)
#ssl_ca_cert_dir = ''
                                   # Directory containing CA root certificate(s)
                                   # (change requires restart)
#ssl_crl_file = ''
                                   # SSL certificate revocation list file
                                   # (change requires restart)

#ssl_ciphers = 'HIGH:MEDIUM:+3DES:!aNULL'
                                   # Allowed SSL ciphers
                                   # (change requires restart)
#ssl_prefer_server_ciphers = off
                                   # Use server's SSL cipher preferences,
                                   # rather than the client's
                                   # (change requires restart)
#ssl_ecdh_curve = 'prime256v1'
                                   # Name of the curve to use in ECDH key exchange
#ssl_dh_params_file = ''
                                   # Name of the file containing Diffie-Hellman parameters used
                                   # for so-called ephemeral DH family of SSL cipher.
#ssl_passphrase_command=''
                                   # Sets an external command to be invoked when a passphrase
                                   # for decrypting an SSL file needs to be obtained
                                   # (change requires restart)

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# POOLS
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# - Concurrent session and pool size -

#num_init_children = 32
                                   # Number of concurrent sessions allowed
                                   # (change requires restart)
#max_pool = 4
                                   # Number of connection pool caches per connection
                                   # (change requires restart)

# - Life time -

#child_life_time = 5min
                                   # Pool exits after being idle for this many seconds
#child_max_connections = 0
                                   # Pool exits after receiving that many connections
                                   # 0 means no exit
#connection_life_time = 0
                                   # Connection to backend closes after being idle for this many seconds
                                   # 0 means no close
#client_idle_limit = 0
                                   # Client is disconnected after being idle for that many seconds
                                   # (even inside an explicit transactions!)
                                   # 0 means no disconnection
```

Does anyone know what this error means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking the postgres logs I found that the problem is being caused by both systems having different versions of collation

The log message instructs to do a database rebuild, I don't need to do that, I don't know if this might cause any problems in the future.

Before performing the steps here, make a backup of your database.

I solved the problem as follows

My master database was created about 3 months ago, my replication database was created recently, that means even the two servers being ubuntu 22.04 their LTS version are different, and it is not solved by a simple `apt upgrade`

The collation versions of my systems are different and to update the master collation I have to update the ubuntu LTS version

I used the following command to update ubuntu master

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

After that I used the following command that I got from the error log itself

```
REINDEX DATABASE {database_name};

ALTER DATABASE <your-database-name> REFRESH COLLATION VERSION;
```

Update by @laurenz-albe